# Custom UITextView Can Not Be Set in Identity Inspector

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, custom-controls

I just want to override a method in UITextView which is canPerformAction. In the overriden method I try to disable "paste:" action. In order to do that I tried to create a new type which will only handles the action not to done. All other uitextview related codes in the default ViewController.swift. So I just added a cocoa touch class in the project and set the target. Here is my custom UITextView's code as looks:
    import UIKit

```
public class CustomTextView: UITextView {

override public func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if action == "paste:" {
        return false
    }
    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
 }

}
```

[image]

When I select one of the uitextviews in the storyboard and view the Identity Inspector pane, I see that I m not able to set my custom class.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried your code and It's working. Just write: `CustomTextView` in your class in main.storyboard.

Comment: after all digging out I have restarted the computer and bazinga!